# Router unable to resolve IPs from parent router

Tags: networking, router, dns

What would suddenly cause a child router to suddenly lose upstream connection to its parent router?

I have a Linksys router connected behind an AT&T router (provided by my ISP), which hosts connections for a few Linux servers. Both routers support wifi, and I'm able to connect through both. When I'm connected to the Linksys's wifi, I can access the servers without issue. However, neither nor them have an Internet connection and can not resolve domains or IPs outside the local network.

This problem only started happening in the last week, and has been otherwise working reliably for over a year. I didn't change anything so I don't know what would be causing the issue.

I tried the obvious pitfalls, like rebooting both routers, but that had no effect.

What's really strange is that sometimes, the connection will come back very briefly. I'll get a valid ping response, but then it'll seemingly cutout and timeout again. Running a `ping` will sometimes look like:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=16.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=15.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=17.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=15.8 ms
From 192.168.1.237 icmp_seq=33 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.237 icmp_seq=36 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.237 icmp_seq=39 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I've configure the Linksys to host itself from 192.168.2.1, and the servers also have a static IPs like 192.168.2.2, 192.168.2.3, etc, so they won't conflict with the AT&T router.

What would be causing the child router to suddenly be unable to access the Internet, when that connection is still available through the parent router?

Comment: What’s a “child” router?

Comment: Make sure the routers are on completely separate subnets, e.g. if the AT&T one provides 10.0.0.0 IP's via DHCP, then use 192.168.0.0 in your "child" (getting *one* of those 10-net IPs) and vice versa. This to ensure that you're not mixing subnets.

Comment: "Destination Host Unreachable" from the system's own address usually means ARP requests to the router fail and can be verified with `arp` (or on Linux with `ip -4 neigh`). There are many possible causes, including bad Wifi signal or multi-homing issues.